# How to redirect links to other link without changing the address bar

Tags: .htaccess

I Want to redirect a link like `http://example.com/username` to `http://example.com/ index.php?id=username`
so that I've used these .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://example.com?id=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But there is a problem. The URLs are redirected, however address bar of browser is changed, too.

How can I redirect the links to other one without changing the address bar?

Comment: I had to remove `R=301` and also `http://myDomain.com` from last line.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a working example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example/
RewriteRule (.*) /foldername/$1 [L]
```